# Redis Database-as-a-Service: What options one have?

Tags: redis

What options there is to use Redis as a service?

Edit:

redistogo.com is one of them

Comment: I just found: https://openredis.com/

Answer (score 7):

Your best option is any of the cloud services that gives you the ability to set up a linux vm - I use rackspace cloud servers myself. Configuration of a new node takes only a few minutes through ssh if you are reusing a standard config, and a server with 512MB RAM will cost around $20/month instead of the $110 redistogo is charging.

Redis isn't particularly well suited to sharing a server. You see that setup a lot with SQL because you have a large, complex system running on the server with user level permissions - It's easy to assign a user account to a customer and they won't be able to interfere with anybody else's data.

Redis does technically have an authentication feature, but it is very basic - it is designed to be run locally or on a trusted local network and if you can connect to the server at all you can access everything. You can make a Redis instance available over the internet, but with the added latency and connection security issues you would lose most of the benefits you get from choosing Redis.

Answer (score 1):

[CloudFoundry](http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20058517-redis-spring-and-cloud-foundry).